# kernel: Intrusion IN=ppp0 on my Fairpoint assigned router from IP in China

Tags: intrusion, router, kernel

I'm getting these user alerts:

```
kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=115.230.125.147 DST=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=107 ID=256 PROTO=TCP SPT=64316 DPT=9064 WINDOW=15500 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
```

And

```
kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=61.240.144.66 DST=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=235 ID=17780 PROTO=TCP SPT=53556 DPT=5000 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
```

The IP addresses appear to be from China. My broadband was off and on about every 30 minutes all weekend, about the same frequency as I get these alerts. How can I prevent this? I have changed my "root" default password and all other user profiles have been disabled. Any help is appreciated. I'm not that technical, but I can configure some basic stuff on my router.

Comment: Cool, now I'm getting them from Fremont, El Jiza, Dusseldorf and Nanchang. The world is now intruding into my router. Glad I posted :/

Comment: what's your routers ID?  At least let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://superuser.com/a/330763

When I first read this I thought it didn't make sense because something cannot 'intrude' in a kernel. However Googling it I found [similar posts](http://forums.techguy.org/general-security/616350-kernel-intrusion-my-router.html) (which also give the answer), but also list that the message was something like:

kernel: Intrusion detected from ...
which means something quite different.

The kernel (software) on your router is letting you know that somebody tried to connect ('intrude') to your WAN IP address.

This happens all the time, entire botnets are dedicated to trying to connect to random IP addresses at certain ports to try default user/password combinations to see if they can find weak security somewhere. However because the router denies this, there is no problem.

Summarizing: the 'intrusions' being detected are harmless, you should worry more about the ones that are not logged ;)